# Making an object move independently in SDL(like a gun shot)

Tags: c++, sdl

I have been following lazyfoos tutorials on SDL, and I have heavily modified his code to make sort of a ship game, that moves around. I'm trying to make the ship shoot, but i have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this. I have the ship and it's movements and the actual application of the image in a class, and I as wondering if anyone had any techniques or certain ways that are efficient in making the ship shoot, making the shot move independently and then disappearing when it goes off screen. I know that I am giving a vague explanation sort of, but I don't want to be given all of the answers, just a little sample code and a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class to hold a projectile, with all the information you need in it, such as this:

```
struct Projectile
{
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;
    shared_ptr<Image> graphic;
    Time time_until_my_destruction;
    bool dead;

    void update(Time time_delta) {
        if(!dead) {
            position += velocity * time_delta;
            time_until_my_destruction -= time_delta;
            if(time_until_my_destruction < 0.0) dead = true;
        }
    }

    void draw(DrawDest & dest) const {
        graphic->draw(dest, position);
    }

    bool checkCollision(const GameObject & object) const {
        return object.area().contains(position);
    }
};
```

This class is not complete obviously, you'll probably want to make adjustments to access levels, and write some constructors and other things, but it should give you the basic idea.

Make a container of those.  When the ship fires, put one into the container.  Each frame, call update, draw, check if the projectile is dead and check for collisions against the game objects.  If a collision occurs, apply damage or whatever.  If the object is dead, remove it from the container.

Comment: The problem with that is, I can't get the position of the ship, which is it's own seperately class, and I need that so I can atleast make it look like the shot is coming out of the ship

Comment: @Stan: Why can't you add a function `getPosition()` to the ship's class?

Comment: Another option is to have the ship generate the projectile itself, using it's own position as the starting location, which makes perfect sense from an object oriented programming perspective, since that's exactly what would happen in real life.

Comment: Your ship should create all projectiles, and your Projectile class should have a static method like: Projectile::New(Position, Velocity);
Then inside your ship class have a Fire method or similar that calls Projectile::New passing its position and velocity.

Comment: @MetaCipher: Not sure why you would need a static method.  Just make a constructor with those same arguments.

Comment: I am still completely lost on how to do this =\

Comment: @Stan: I don't really know how to make this more clear to you without giving you a full tutorial on game programming.  I'd suggest you finish the Lazy Foo tutorials.  Pay particular attention to Lesson 28 on particles, because it does something similar to projectiles.  Also lesson 32, frame independent movement is quite important.  Make sure you fully understand at least up to that.

Answer (score 0):

I can only absolutely recommend [Aaron's Game Programming Tutorials](http://www.aaroncox.net/tutorials/arcade/index.html), it uses C++ and SDL.